# Direct limit of totally ordered system of isomorphic $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose we have a directed system of $C^*$-algebras $A_i$

$$\{A_i,\phi_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}},$$

such that each $*$-homomorphism $\phi_i:A_i\rightarrow A_{i+1}$ is an inclusion. Furthermore, suppose that all of the $A_i$ are (abstractly) isomorphic.

**Question:** Is it true that the direct limit of this system is isomorphic to each $A_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take for instance $A_j=B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ for all $j$, and use  embeddings
$$
T\longmapsto \begin{bmatrix} T&0\\0&T\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
The direct limit has no minimal projections, so it cannot be isomorphic to $B(H)$.

If you want a separable example, you can use $K(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ instead.